# Reading fortran binary data with python, floats and ints

Tags: python, binary, fortran

A have a file that can be read using fortran, and produces the following output:

```
  0     2044150      229424           0           0           0   
0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000       
2.97821895219385624E-003   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        
0.0000000000000000       7.81250000000000000E-003   127.00000000000000                0           0           0    91948296    10067568     7115688           0  
0           0          48   67.769999999999996       
0.30700001120567322       0.69300001859664917       0.67769998311996460
```

Basically some int*4 values and some float*8 values (in the header).
I want to be able to read this data file in using python. I used the following code:

```
f = open(fname,'rb')
data = np.fromfile(file=f,dtype=np.int32)
print data
```

and i get the result:

```
[       256          0    2044150     229424          0          0
      0          0          0          0          0  536870912
 1063806407          0          0          0          0          0
      0          0   ]
```

Some of the numbers are ok, and I believe that the 256 refers to the record size.
However, when I try to read in the floats (by changing np.int32 to np.float64) I get

```
[  1.26480805e-321   4.86836763e-309   0.00000000e+000  0.00000000e+000
   0.00000000e+000   1.49166815e-154   5.25590200e-315       0.00000000e+000
   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   5.26354425e-315   5.33599245e-315
   0.00000000e+000   9.12063001e-306   3.51561699e-317   0.00000000e+000
  -1.02951130e-086   2.68156223e+154   2.68156222e+154  -2.68156222e+154]
```

Which is clearly wrong not just for the int32s but also for the float 64s I was trying to read.

I have thought maybe this was something to do with big/littlendian but haven't found a fix. I am also sure that I am trying to read in the correct data type (float64) and have tried many others and they produce similar (or worse) results.

I know that the format of the header is 
int*4(6),real*8(6),real*8,real*8,int*4,int*4,int*4(6),int*4,int*4,real*8,real*8,real*8,real*8,character(96)

Comment: you cannot read a mixed format file by specifying either int or float. You have to choose. Maybe you could try with `struct.unpack`

Comment: With previous files I have opened them twice, using fromfile with dtype=int once, then reopened the same file and used fromfile with dtype=float and that has previously worked fine. My reason for posting the question is that this seemed somehow inexplicably different.

Comment: the trouble is the file starts with 7 4-byte integers.(counting the header) Being odd you are not aligned correctly if you simply read the whole thing as 8 byte values.

Answer (score 0):

Your data file lacks structure. You should know what's in the file first and then pick a reading strategy, else you will read digits but won't know what they mean. As Jean-François Fabre write, `loadtxt` cannot handle your situation, you will have to code in the logic for the file yourself. You can delegate the parsing of the numerical parts to `loadtxt` part by part, using StringIO for instance https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO

Comment: Perhaps you missed the fact that the data is binary?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the struct.unpack method suggested above.
My code looks something like:

```
def read_block(start,data_format,data):

    p = start # Count block size

    # Read record size
    rf = 'i'
    rs = struct.calcsize(rf)
    record = struct.unpack(rf,data[p:p+rs])
    p += rs

    bs = record[0]
    body = list(struct.unpack(data_format,data[p:p+bs]))
    p += bs

    p += rs # Record size again

    return body,p-start


''' Read specific file architecture '''
''' Easily modified '''
def read_gadget(gdt_file):

    p = 0

    with open(gdt_file,'rb') as binary_file:
        data = binary_file.read()


    header_fmt = '=6i8d10i4d96s'    
    header,header_size = read_block(p,header_fmt,data)
    npart = header[:6]
    mpart = header[6:12]
    npart_tot = sum(npart)
    p += header_size


    pos_fmt = str(3*npart_tot)+'f'
    pos_list,pos_size = read_block(p,pos_fmt,data)
    pos_arr = np.zeros((npart_tot,3))
    for i in range(3):
        pos_arr[:,i] = np.array(pos_list)[i*npart_tot:(i+1)*npart_tot]
    p += pos_size


    vel_fmt = str(3*npart_tot)+'f'
    vel_list,vel_size = read_block(p,vel_fmt,data)
    vel_arr = np.zeros((npart_tot,3))
    for i in range(3):
        vel_arr[:,i] = np.array(vel_list)[i*npart_tot:(i+1)*npart_tot]
    p += vel_size

    id_fmt = str(npart_tot)+'l'
    id_list,id_size = read_block(p,id_fmt,data)
    p += id_size
    id_arr = np.array(id_list)


    mass_arr = np.array([])
    for i in range(6):
        if npart[i]==0:
            pass
        elif npart[i]!=0 and mpart[i]==0:
            mass_fmt = str(npart[i])+'f'
            mass_list,mass_size = read_block(p,mass_fmt,data)
            p += mass_size
            mass_arr = np.append(mass_arr,np.array(mass_list))
        elif npart[i]!=0 and mpart[i]!=0:
            mass_list = npart[i]*[mpart[i]]
            mass_arr = np.append(mass_arr,np.array(mass_list))


    return header,pos_arr,vel_arr,id_arr,mass_arr
```

Comment: since you know the structure you could just do a sequence of `np.fromfile` calls using the third argument to specify how many items of each type to read.